# How to remove a word appear at the end of each link

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Many links 404 ending with this word
undefined
Example :
http://cima4up.tv/%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%84%D9%85-teraa-surroor-2016-%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%85/undefined

I want to remove this word (undefined) from all the links and redirect it to the link without undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/undefined$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```